# Computer Embezzlement Movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a movie that is pretty old - from when computers used punch cards. The plot is that a rich man (wealthy industrialist?) is trying to start a coup in a country (I think the USA), and he's using a big computer to deal with all the administration (hiring agents, etc). One of his employees, who is not the protagonist, is embezzling lots of the money by feeding false reports to the computer and hiring non-existent agents.

The protagonist is sort of an observer, but I think near the end he is semi-framed by the embezzler, and gets caught in a security cage (a bit like the mantrap in sneakers). At the end of the film, the industrialist triggers the coup, but it fails because most of the agents dont actually exist.

Comment: This does not appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy as defined in the [FAQ]

Comment: I do know a movie with the computer/coup/fake agents elements but the rest (2nd paragraph) does not agree.

Comment: @Paulie_D - What's the movie? If OP confirms it's correct and it's off-topic, we can happily shut this one down. If OP confirms it's correct and it's on-topic, you can post it as an answer

Comment: [Billion Dollar Brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_Dollar_Brain). While *silly* I don't think it's SF&F.

Comment: "*He thinks Leo has hired hundreds of Latvian agents but there are only a handful, as Leo is pocketing the money*" - Sounds like this is the right film based on OP's description. It's not on-topic as it's basically spy-fi.

Comment: Unfortunately, the identification of works that do not contain any sci-fi or fantasy (or related) elements is not within the scope of this community. But if you are looking to identify an on-topic work, please [edit] your question and share more details about its sci-fi or fantasy aspects so that we can better help you. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: Thanks, it was Billion Dollar Brain! It felt a bit more sci-fi when I first saw it.